# How to get data in json format from translate.googleapis.com?

Tags: php, json, google-translate

I am trying to use google trnslation apis to translate some texts from English to Dutch. I have the following code:-

```
$text = urlencode($text);
$from_lan = 'en';
$to_lan = 'nl';
$url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=p&sl=".$from_lan."&tl=".$to_lan."&dt=t&q=".$text;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($content);
```

The data which I am getting is:-

```
[[["uitzicht","view",,,2]],,"en"]
```

It is not array or json data. It is string. How can I get data in json format

Comment: It is not array or json data . it's look like array

Comment: If output is array then use json_encode() to convert string into json.

Comment: The data is actually string coming with brackets and braces. @Anant

Comment: @Saswat   check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/34919660/4248328  OR question code of this:- http://stackoverflow.com/q/35013483/4248328

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicate comma's using a regex. Then encode/parse to json. This works in js, but not tested in php.

Here's js/jquery versions for comparison:

```
// error
$.ajax({
    url: "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=nl&dt=t&q=view",
    dataType: "text"
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data)[0][0][0]);
  });

// works (replaces duplicate comma's with single ones)
$.ajax({
    url: "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=nl&dt=t&q=view",
    dataType: "text"
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.replace(/,+/g, ","))[0][0][0]);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Json Decode (Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable)

```
var_dump(json_decode($content)); //Output is object variable
var_dump(json_decode($content, true)); //Output is array variable
```